# Why are num_get and num_put asymmetric?

Tags: c++, locale, iostream

The arithmetic extraction operator for `std::basic_istream` has [non-virtual overloads for all 8 integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) (not listing chars, which are handled differently anyway), and it calls `num_get::get`, which has individual [*virtual* overloads for 6 of them](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) (missing signed versions of short and int)

The arithmetic insertion operator for `std::basic_ostream` also has [non-virtual overloads for all 8 integer types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), and it calls `num_put::put`, which only has [virtual overloads for 4 types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_put/put), which are `long`, `long long` and their unsigned variants. For the smaller types, the insertion operator performs integer promotions.

Why a gap in what is otherwise a tour-de-force of user extensibility? Is seems impossible to provide user-defined handling for each integer type (e.g. to build a type-preserving serialization library on top of iostream interface), and moreso, it is asymmetric. It could have been achieved with little effort. Is there a trade-off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Standard C++ Iostreams and Locales](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=5qybChHSk7QC&pg=PA288&lpg=PA288&dq=%22at+first+sight+it+might+look+as+if+versions+of+put%28%29%22&source=bl&ots=dpfS6B0q4_&sig=xJogbk_4iA1HRcxYoffZ3amDDDo&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=eVhkUcrtMsnxiAeE34CYDg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22at%20first%20sight%20it%20might%20look%20as%20if%20versions%20of%20put%28%29%22&f=false):

> At first sight it might look as if versions of put() for short, int,
>   or float are missing. The intent was to keep the interface of the
>   standard library concise, and a value of type short or int can be
>   handled by the version of long. Similarly, a value of type float can
>   be handled by the put() version of double.

and then later on about `num_get::get()`:

> Again, as with num_put::put(), the types that are not absolutely
>   necessary are omitted.

Comment: But the intent of the question was to ask why modularity was decided against - e.g. custom num_put and num_get that allowed binary I/O with the formatted input/output operators.

Comment: @LB--: I believe that is sufficiently explained in both answers. What did you miss?

Comment: I don't see how the rationale applies when one wants to preserve type information in `num_put`, such as for binary output.

Comment: @LB--: That simply wasn't considered important, you could consider that as a defect, but that is another issue.

Answer (score 4):

When you're reading values you have to allow for overflows, so need an extractor for each type. When you're writing values you don't, so the largest type is sufficient. Back in the olden days the largest type was `long`. When `long long` was added, the version for `long` was kept for backward compatibility.